# Eclipse GEF - Select figures

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef

I am using the GEF framework to show a network of connected nodes. I have a topEditPart for the Diagram and one editPart each for the node and its connections. The diagram is rendering properly. Now I need to select a Node and all the outgoing connections and the connected nodes should change to a different color. I started off to look at the EditPolicies that GEF provides, but I have no clue which edit policy to use to highlight a figure ie., show a selection feedback. any help in this regard is much appreciated.
This is what I have tried:

I created class extending `XYLayoutEditPolicy` and installed it on the rootEditPart

```
public class BasicXYLayoutEditPolicy extends XYLayoutEditPolicy {
    protected Command createAddCommand(EditPart child, Object constraint) {
        return null;
    }

    protected Command createChangeConstraintCommand(EditPart child, Object constraint) {
        return null;
    }

    protected Command getCreateCommand(CreateRequest request) {
        return null;
    }

    protected EditPolicy createChildEditPolicy(EditPart child) {
        return new NodeResizableEditPolicy(); 
    }

    protected Command getDeleteDependantCommand(Request request) {
        return null;
    }

    public EditPart getTargetEditPart(Request request) {
        EditPart targetEditPart = getHost(); // I guessed that...
        return targetEditPart;
    }
}
```

Installed on Root editpart

```
protected void createEditPolicies() {
    installEditPolicy(EditPolicy.LAYOUT_ROLE, new BasicXYLayoutEditPolicy());
}
```

Now I create a new class `NodeSelectionEditPolicy` which extends `SelectionEditPolicy`

```
public class NodeSelectionEditPolicy extends SelectionEditPolicy {

    @Override
    protected void hideSelection() {
        getHostFigure().setBackgroundColor(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GREEN));
    }

    @Override
    protected void showSelection() {
        getHostFigure().setBackgroundColor(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_RED));
    }
}
```

Next I am installing this policy onto the Node Edit parts

```
protected void createEditPolicies() {
    installEditPolicy(EditPolicy.SELECTION_FEEDBACK_ROLE, new NodeSelectionEditPolicy());
}
```

When I execute this code, nothing seems to happen ie., no visual selection feedback happens. am I missing something ? do I need to implement any method of `NodeSelectionEditPolicy` ?

Answer (score 0):

Extending `SelectionEditPolicy` is the right way to go and should be working (in your code it will only change the color of the selected figure).

The problem could be that the figure does not have a background color therefore changing the background color doesn't do much. Try changing the foreground color.

Comment: When the diagram is loaded initially, only the hideSelection() method of NodeSelectionEditPolicy is called. But after that when I select a Node (which I am having as a RoundedRectangle), nothing happen... I can see that showSelection() method is not called. does that give you a clue. By the way, I will try changing the foreground color

Comment: I may be wrong. But do I need to implement the method activate() to get the desired results ?

Comment: I used a eclipse view to host my diagram EditParts rather than a `GraphicalEditor`. This caused all the confusion. Now selection, Drag , resize everything is working fine. Thank you for your time and your tutorials at http://www.vainolo.com/tutorials/gef-tutorials/. Part 3 of this series helped me to nail down the issue